# How to create Array of dynamically generated elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have dynamic table generated with jQuery `.append()`:

```
$el.append('<tr data-id=' + data[i].id + ' data-token=' + data[i].token + '><td>' + data[i].order + '</td>\n\<td><input name="qty" id="qty" type="number" value="' + data[i].qty + '" min="1"></td>\n\...
```

I would like click button and if `checkbox` is `checked` then pick one of these values in `tr` tag and create array. For example `data[i].id`:

```
$('body').on('click', '#button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
    ids = [],
    id = tr.data('id');

    $('.group:checked').each(function(i, e) {
        ids.push(id);
    });
    alert(ids.join());
});
```

However in this scenario the array is empty because `id` is `undefined` but if I change code to `ids.push($(this).val())` then output is something like `on,on,on` (showing checkbox values). But won't work with `tr` tags

I found a solution. I move variables from first function into second:

```
$('body').on('click', '#button', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  
 var ids = [];
  $('.group:checked').each(function(i, e) {
      var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
      id = tr.data('id');
    ids.push(id);
    });
    alert(ids.join());
});
```

Comment: Where is the `#button` and the checkbox in your HTML?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan button is also generated with id='button'. and it works (when i clicking i can have oupbut alert etc)

Comment: So any ideas how to pick value from tr?

Comment: Yes, but not in your case as you've missed out half of the relevant HTML.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this is not related with rest of the code. Please see my solution above

Comment: It's entirely related as the button and checkbox is what the code hinges on. You at least need to use a class for the button instead of duplicating it's `id` everywhere.

Comment: Your code works now simply because you didn't describe your issue accurately. **You seem to intend to create an array of the ids of all `<tr>` whose checkboxes are checked**, but did not mention as such in your question or your original code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my id button exist in table (as first row in a table) and i don't need to use class for one item. i'm using class for checkbox'es because i have more then one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding `click` event on `id` and `IDS must be unique` as you would be generating multiple rows and each row would have a `button` you can assign a `class` to button and bind click on `class`

```js
var ids = [];
$('body').on('click', '.button', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
    id = tr.data('id');

  if (tr.find('.group').is(":checked"))
    ids.push(id);
});
```

Also you will need to check the `checkbox` in `current row`.If you need `array` to be filled with `multiple values` you need to create it outside the function.

Edit

If you want to get `id` of those rows where `checkbox is checked`. You can do this

```
var ids = [];
$('body').on('click', '#button', function (e) {
  $('.group:checked').each(function () {
      ids.push($(this).closest("tr").data("id"));
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the `.data()`method in jQuery is a read only method. So when creating dynamic `DOM` elements with a data attribute the best way to access them is using `.attr('data-id')`in your case.

From the API: [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

> The `data-` attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).

Comment: Sorry, but this is completely incorrect in all aspects.

Comment: No. `.data()` is able to access the HTML5 data attribute. It simply cannot write to it. [From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2): "`.data(key)`: Return the value at the named data store for the first element in the jQuery collection, as set by `data(name, value)` **or by an HTML5 data-* attribute**." (emphasis my own)